# Horizontally center a responsive image in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

If an image with `.img-responsive` class has less width than the container width then it displays as aligned to left. Adding `.text-center` to parent element does not seem to work. Here is an example:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
  <img src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="Example Image" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `.img-responsive class` has its CSS `display` property set to `block`. Adding `.img-responsive { display: inline-block; }` in user stylesheet will solve the issue by overriding the original value and image will display as centred.

Here is CSS:

```
.img-responsive {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
  <img src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="Example image" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to follow the twitter bootstrap synthax, you should use the **`center-block`** class as explained in the documentation.

**[Link to the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive)**

**Kind of code** :

```
<img class="center-block" src="something.xxx" alt="xxx">
```

Comment: Agree and appreciate that. I was wondering how did I miss that when I encountered this problem first time a few months ago. I checked from WayBack Machine and figured that they only added reference to this in April this year. Ref: http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: It works like a charm. I appreciate this answer; it is simple and does not require to override the bootstrap file.

Comment: @mtyson Yes i's nice isn't it ? Instead of put a comment like this, why don't you explain in sharing your code why you say this ?

Comment: I've tried this one several times over the years, and it just never seems to work.  Does nothing... shamefully, I just abandoned hand-coded bootstrap for Wix :O

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-align` property on it's parent element

```
.text-centre {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This won't work. The `text-align` should be added to the parent element of responsive image.

Comment: You are missing the point I guess. `text-center` class is already there in parent element but it is not working because: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30103365/428901

Comment: @JabranRafique Spelling mistake in the class name